# Flex direction column is ignored if one of the child has relative postion

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the code below.

On the `.container` I set

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to make my `previous` and `next` arrow to go before and after the container `items`. It doesn't work the flex direction remains row.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.item>* {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.previous::before,
.next::before {
  color: #9e9e9e;
  font: 400 1.5rem/1 iconfont !important;
  speak: none;
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="previous">S</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">S</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually  you need to remove `flex-direction: column` from `.container`, because you are trying to create a row by putting the arrows inline with the items

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.items {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  justify-content: center
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.item>* {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.previous::before,
.next::before {
  color: #9e9e9e;
  font: 400 1.5rem/1 iconfont !important;
  speak: none;
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="previous">S</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">S</div>
</div>
```